# Starting an ASP Session

Tags: asp-classic

I am working on a system using ASP that requires session control. What is the syntax for starting and retrieving a session value using ASP?

Comment: Take a look at ASP.NET State Management Overview - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s. This can be your starting point. Also, take a look at ASP.NET Session State Overview - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581

Answer (score 2):

Before someone shouts at your for not using Google first check out the below link

http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_sessions.asp

Answer (score 2):

Syntax:

```
<% Session[.collection|property|method|event] %>
```

Example

```
<% Option Explicit %>
<html>
<head>
<title>First Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
    Session.TimeOut  = 60
    Session("SiteName") = "www.example.com"
    Session("Name") = "Mr.Incredible"
    Response.write("Session Created<br><br>")
    Response.write("<a href=redirect.asp>Check Session</a>")
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Redirect Page:

```
<% Option Explicit %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Redirect Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
    Response.write "Site Name = " & Session("SiteName") & "<br>"
    Response.write "Name = " & Session("Name")& "<br><br>"
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
      Session("name") = "something"   //storing value in session


      something = Session("name") //retrieving value from session
```